# Does Raspberry Pi Zero show any screen if turned on without a SD Card?

Tags: pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero without a SD Card. I bought a HDMI to VGA cable and I am currently testing the cable but nothing displays on the screen. Does the Pi not display anything or does it have something to do with the cable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Raspberry Pi there is no signal on HDMI unless the VideoCore IV Chip has been initialized. This is done by reading the special firmware (bootcode.bin/start.elf) from the boot partition. So unless you have an SD-Card present, you won't be able to see anything.

Comment: Thanks. I added a SD card with the OS installed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

No ( from a poor experience of mine )